# you have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .NET framing. it is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint

Tags: c#, wcf, nettcpbinding, basichttpbinding

I have a WCF service hosted in IIS. 
I am consuming this service in my .NET winform application.
but at point where i am making a call to service i am getting folloing error:
**you have tried to create a channel to a service that does not support .NET framing. it is possible that you are encountering an HTTP endpoint**
does anyone has any idea about this issue ?
how can i resolve it ?
code for calling service methods is like below code:

```
 ServiceReference1.SizeAdjustmentAIFServiceClient client = new SizeAdjustmentAIFServiceClient();
            dtRBOStoreTable dtoTable = client.getStoreDetail(input);
```

app.configFile

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
            <basicHttpBinding>
                <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ISizeAdjustmentAIFService" />
            </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:9999/SizeAdjustmentAIFService.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ISizeAdjustmentAIFService"
                contract="ServiceReference1.ISizeAdjustmentAIFService" name="BasicHttpBinding_ISizeAdjustmentAIFService" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had faced same issue however, I found that I was hitting http end point where as I configured net.tcp one. So similar might be the case with you. Is it possible for you to check this?